# Show a div when clicking on a link inside a table cell

Tags: jquery, toggle

Probably very simple thing, but I can't figure it out.
I want to toggle the visibility of a div, when clicking on a link.

So this is my situation

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
      <td>
         <a onclick='showDiv' />
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<div name='divToShow' style='display:none;' />
```

The code I had so far:

```
// Then show the panel with substitute information
var control = $(parent).parent().parent().parent().find('div[name$="divToShow"]');
control.toggle();
```

So I'm not sure how to achieve this.
Anyone?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: .parent().parent().parent()... better closest(selector)

Answer (score 1):

Why not assigning an ID to the div and then show it using $('#id').toggle()?

Basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/fVXAC/

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery's **toggle()** function.

something like;

```
$('#clickme').toggle(
function() {
    $('#mydiv').css({ 'display':'block' });
}, function() {
    $('#mydiv').css({ 'display':'none' });
});
```

Here is the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CXHAW/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Eez4g/1/

I think that's what you are trying to do

Comment: Ah, that is something that would work. What if I want to extract the inline code to a separate function? What parameters should I work with?

Answer (score 0):

Elements like `<a>` and `<div>` needs to be closed with `</a>` and `</div>`, and are not self closing.

An `<a>` element should also have a `href` attribute, even if it's just `href="#"`.

```
$("a[onclick='showDiv']")​​​.on('click', function(e) { //find element based on onclick, would be better with an ID
    e.preventDefault(); //all <a> elements should have a href
    $(this).closest('table').next($("[name='divToShow']")).toggle();
})​​​​;​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BnETg/)

If you start by understanding HTML and writing the correct markup, using javascript will become a lot easier for you.

Comment: Thanks, I know all that, but it was just to outline the case.